# How to change the handler associated with a servlet in a running application server?

Tags: tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee, grpc

I want to figure out how can we change the server configurations such as handlers, the business logic etc. in a running application server without restarting the server.

Finally, if let's say I wanted to use `gRPC` as communication method for the api calls to the backend then what are there application servers that I can use to dynamically change the configuration of the server without restarting the server itself?

Comment: If you redeploy an application you can do almost anything within it and You do not have to restart the server. In most production software you have a proxy service. This way you can deploy the new application and if everything is running smoothly you alter the proxy to the new service. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @Mark Thanks for your answer, are there any tutorials/example code that you know of that you could point to about using this proxy service idea. I think this could be the right answer. I couldn't find any specific resources about redeploying an application where you also change the handlers, any walkthrough guide will be great. Finally the question has a second part about running a gRPC server. AFAICT servers like tomcat can support the use of gRPC. Am I correct?

Comment: I think I'll do it in an answer. :)

Comment: According to http://www.grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/java.html you can use it on tomcat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to offer your services without any downtime you can use proxy servers to handle the incoming traffic. The easy ones do not use any kind of load balancing, but there are a lot of nice features you can use.

I really like to use the [`Apache HTTPD`](https://httpd.apache.org/) (also known as [`apache2`](https://httpd.apache.org/)) as a proxy service. There is a module called [`mod_proxy`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html). This way you can route your traffic to various backend service as follows:

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/warname1/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/warname1/
ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain  "localhost:8080"  "public.example.com"
```

There is a great tutorial in [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension) about this kind of proxy.

To switch the implementation you can create an another `war`/`ear` fullfilling the new requirements and deploy to the server. Check if everything is OK and you can just easily alter the `httpd` configuration to use the new versions.